# How @PreAuthorize checks the roles?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have several REST APIs.

I would like to put Security on top of all of them, in order to allowed the functionalities only for certain roles.

I put the @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) in the configuration class.

I have a DB with a table which stores the roles.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") 
public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper> getError(...


INSERT INTO table USER_ROLE VALUES ('ADMIN','PASSWORD','ROLE_ADMIN');
```

How can the method "hasRole" query the table USER_ROLE?
Is there any setting that I must give to Spring in order to communicate with that table?

Comment: Basically I would like to understand how the @PreAuthorize communicates with the table where I store the several roles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure you add the following to your configuration:

Annotation style:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
```

XML Style:

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>
```

[It's all in the spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#el-pre-post-annotations).

Using `@Pre` and `@Post` annotations requires you to have first set up spring security in your project. User roles are loaded during authentication in the standard implementation.

It doesn't check your table when checking the annotation (by default), it just checks the `Principal` (User) object in  memory for the list of assigned `GrantedAuthority` (Roles).

*A closer look...*

Take a look at the [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-authentication-userdetailsservice) interface, this returns an instance of [UserDetails](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) (the `Principal`). This is where we fetch your "user" from the database.

The `UserDetails` interface defines a method called `getAuthorities()` that returns a `Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority>`, essentially your `Role` table. This is where the "Roles" make it into memory, and can be later checked by the `@Pre` and `@Post` annotations.

The implementation I've explained above can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/).

Comment: I put the annotation in the Configuration file.. 
I don't understand if the role is a parameter of the user, o parameter of the request, or if I must setup something to arrange the communications between the "hasrole" method and the table...

Comment: You have to set up something similar to what I have now explained in the answer.