# Reading ROLES from Azure AD to Spring Boot OAuth2

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot

I have a ResourceServer using Spring Boot Oauth2, where my controller have the following:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('search_price')")
    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        return "OK !!";
    }
}
```

So, i have a token generated by Azure AD that have this role in your claims, like bellow:

```
...
"idp": "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxx/",
  "oid": "e224xxxxxxxx6faf",
  "roles": [
    "search_price"
  ],
  "sub": "e2240xxxxxxx",
  "tid": "a753xxxxxxxxxx177e575",
...
```

When i try to HIT this endpoint from POSTMAN i got: Access is denied. If i remove "@PreAuthorize" annotation everything works, but i need it.

Looking inside **DefaultAccessTokenConverter** class , in method **extractAuthentication** i found the following:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = null;
        if (user == null && map.containsKey("authorities")) {
            String[] roles = (String[])((Collection)map.get("authorities")).toArray(new String[0]);
            authorities = AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(roles);
        }
```

So, in default the converter don't read **ROLES** claim, just **authorities** and Azure AD don't have this last.

Comment: Did you try `(@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42636147/7073340)

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it